# Animation timeline organization for Unity 5

Tags: animation, unity

I create stuff for AssetStore and use 3ds max and Unity 5.

Can someone tell me how I need to work with timeline?

When I create animation for several objects, I need to animate them one by one? (Example: from Frame 0 to Frame 60 object 01 rotates 360 degrees, then from Frame 60 to Frame 120 object 02 rotates 360 degrees) OR I need to animate every one object in same time. (Every one rotates from Frame 0 to Frame 60).

I know that I need to assign animation controllers in Unity, and if I create all animations in same time, I need only one controller for many objects.

If there, any benefits to animate objects one by one and have multiple controllers later in game development?

Comment: Ruben Torres Bonet - thanks a lot for your answer. I understand that i need only one animation controller and i can animate all similar object in same time, not one by one. One little question remains - how to animate every object in different times (keyframes) and how i can use animation layers?

Answer (score 2):

You can add an animation controller in the root object of all your objects so they share it. And then, in every animation clip you want, you can animate every object you want in different times (keyframes).

A single animation controller should be cohesive (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)); that means, it should focus on the animations that its name tell about. If it is called "CharacterAnimationController", then it should animate characters but never doors. Otherwise you will have difficulties finding it and maintaining it.

You can also use different animation layers if you want semi-independent animation controller states. But try to follow the KISS principle and avoid overengineering everything.